# What is the general proof that the torque acting on an irregular current carrying loop in an uniform magnetic field is only dependent on area?

Tags: magnetic-fields, electric-current, torque

How do you prove that the torque acting on an irregular current carrying loop in an uniform magnetic field in the plane of loop =  $I \vec{A} \times \vec{B}$

Where,

$ \vec{A}$ = Area vector of the loop
$ \vec{B}$ = Constant magnetic field in the plane of the loop
$I$ = current flowing through the loop

I can prove it for specific cases of circular loop or rectangular one but what is the general proof?

Comment: I would suggest that it comes from the integral version of Faraday's law. If you take the local version and apply the divergence theorem, the only thing that matters is the area of the loop.

Comment: Ok, thanks. Will have a look at divergence theorem.